# How to use typeahead options in Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using [Bootstrap tags input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) with [typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and I was wondering how can I set the default options to **typeaheadjs**. In the [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) I've seen something like this:

```
var input = $('input');
input.tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'value',
    itemText: 'text',
    typeaheadjs: {
        name: 'engine',
        displayKey: 'text',
        source: engine.ttAdapter()
}
```

Here, **typeaheadjs** represent a dataset, but how can I add the basic options like **hint**, **highlight**, **minLength**?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can give add typeaheadjs as an array of objects. First object being options and second datasets

> typeaheadjs: [ {options}, {datasets} ]

Something like this should do.

```
$('input').tagsinput({
    typeaheadjs: [{
          minLength: 3,
          highlight: true
    },{
        minlength: 3,
        name: 'citynames',
        displayKey: 'name',
        valueKey: 'name',
        source: citynames.ttAdapter()
    }],
    freeInput: true
});
```

Here is a ***[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aawmp3np/305/)***

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see... thanks @DhirajBodicherla that doesn't work using the package from the [examples site](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). It seems to be out of date. I've tried with the master branch and it works perfectly, Thanks!

Comment: The demo does not appear to be functional.  Typeahead is not working.

Comment: @ctorx: It is working. Start typing for a word and it'll work

Comment: [The demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/aawmp3np/35/) is functional, but funky... the textbox changes in size as you type...

Comment: The demo works perfect for me but I cannot seem to get the tyepahead functionality using my own site.  The tags work but I don't see a list of data that I can choose from.  I even copied and pasted the demo to try it out.

Comment: @Deep3015 and tyelford The demo seems to be working. Min length is 3 hence you were not able to see a list. Type at least 3 characters

Comment: @Dhiraj I am saying how to send the selected value from the input via ajax. Input tags are not normal input values ,they are span elements.

Comment: @Deep3015 Firstly, your question is not a scope of this post. You should have asked another question. From the top of my head `$('input-element-to-which-tagsinput-is-hooked-to').val()` should work.

Comment: @Dhiraj check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/jjcsuqvz/) is not giving result as suggested

Comment: @Deep3015 It should be `alert($('.category-container > > input').val());` because tagsinput stores the values inside `.data()` and not as a value in the input. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/jjcsuqvz/1/